# Using \include with in Tabular / Array

Tags: tables, include

I'm doing graphics using PStricks, writing each figure in it's own sub-file.
I would like to order two of these figure vertically with a symbol in between.

To that end, I've tried using a tabular and arrays environments. This, however, produces and error, even when the sub-file is empty.

For PStricks, I compile using xelatex on Ubuntu.

A minimal working example is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\include{test} & b & c\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here, the error is produced at `\end{frame}`. `test.tex` is empty and is in the same folder as the main file.

Is there away to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\input{test}` instead of `\include{test}`. The former gives the same as typing the contents of `test.tex` into your main file, while the latter inserts `\clearpage` before and after, as well as doing some trickery to write a separate `.aux` file for each included file.

`\include` is useful for e.g. the case where you divide a text into chapters, with one chapter in each file, but for cases such as this, where you want to put the code for a `pstricks` drawing in a separate file, `\input` should be used.

For more details see [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)